# How to change the weather in a private session of GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I know cheats are not allowed in *GTA Online*, so I'm looking for another way to change the weather.

I have a private session for friends in GTA Online where the weather needs to change.  How can I do this?  **Specifically in GTA Online, not in single player.**

Maybe some kind of glitch or cheat - just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only select weather in GTA Online through some [jobs](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Jobs_in_GTA_Online) (some jobs have a pre-scripted weather) and through custom jobs created in the [Content Creator](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Content_Creator).

**In GTA Online [free mode](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Free_Mode), you can't select or change the weather**, unless you use mods. Free mode weather is set server-side and can't be changed unless you use mods or other exploits which could cause your account to be suspended or banned.

> Any attempt to tamper with the behavior of GTA Online by installing or
> executing mods, scripts, or other exploits, modifying the game files
> or manipulating the game in any way while it is executing will result
> in disciplinary action including but not limited to time in the
> cheater pool, bans and potential suspension of your account

- [Rockstar Games Support article, "Update on GTA Online Cheaters and Modded GTA$"](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/201617423/Update-on-GTA-Online-Cheaters-and-Modded-GTA)